# Errors in Typescript example

Tags: typescript

I am a beginner in learning Typescript, following the tutorial in this [Youtube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k5E2AVpwsko&t=1222s). I have reached a point at time approx 1 hr 20 min in, I have the following code which matches the example given in the tutorial:

point.ts

```
export class Point {
  constructor(private _x?: number, private _y?:number) {}

  draw() {
    console.log('x:'+this._x+' y:'+this._y);
  }
}
```

main.ts

```
import { Point } from './point'; 

let point = new Point(1,2);

point.draw();
```

But this does not work.
When I transpile and run, I get the error:

```
$ tsc --target es5 main.ts && node main.js 
main.ts:1:23 - error TS2306: File '/home/nick/dev/angular/hello/ts/point.ts' is not a module.

1 import { Point } from './point';

Found 1 error.
```

EDIT: Typescript version 3.3.1

FURTHER EDIT: I am on Linux. A colleague has tried it on Windows. Same version of Typescript. No errors. I suspect a bug in the Linux version. Can anyone confirm?

Comment: It should work.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't.

Comment: I work on Linux too, same TS version. But I always define the configuration in a `tsconfig.json` file. Maybe you should begin here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html .

Comment: I just tried your code with your command and it works. Does the file `/home/nick/dev/angular/hello/ts/point.ts` of your error message exists?

Comment: yes, it did exist.

Comment: And the content of `point.ts` is exactly what you posted here? With the `export` keyword and no namespace?

Comment: Yes, the code was copied/pasted exactly.